# How to add a Startup Shortcut to a User that has never logged-in (profile not created)?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I am currently installing my software under an administrator account, at the end of the process I need to add a Startup Shortcut to UserX, however this UserX has not logged onto the system yet and thus there is no profile for them under \USERS\ (or equivalent folder depending on the version of Windows).

Is there any suggestion or solution for this? Today I have to place it under AllUsers but this has the negative side-effect of starting the application when I login to the ADMIN account (which is totally wrong).

Currently I need to support Windows XP, 7, and 10.

Today I use a VBScript with WMI to iterate over the ProfileLists (under  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList) to find my user (which is not there yet) and use objWshShell.CreateShortcut with the correct paths - works great if the user profile exists and for AllUsers as well, but I can't find a solution for the case where the user has never logged in (like a DOMAIN user - which is my main concern).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can add a shortcut to a non-existing user yet, so the way to go is launching it at every startup, and determine if the script has run before or not.

You can do this by either placing a value in the registry or placing a file in their profile directory (better option) and check for its existence.

If for some reason you need to relaunch the script to everyone, you simply remove the value from the registry or their profile directory.

It works because of the following technique.

When a user logs in for the first time, the very first thing that is being done, is: A profile folder is being made locally, an existing one is synced from the server.

This is necessary because installations etc, that happen during login will need this to be there, and other settings such as group policies are stored there as well.

The logon script is executed at the end of the login, and at this point the profile directory exists.

Now, given that this is the first time it has run, checking for the file: *%APPDATA%\installed.dat* can be used to see if the script has run before or not. The very first login, that file is not there, so the script continues to do its thing and the install. At the very end, we create the file *%APPDATA%\installed.dat* and the script ends normally.

At next logon, all files already exists, so during login, the sync with the server is executed. It will update any changes, but the installed.dat file will be synched too, so the login script will now find the file and can abort the script instead of doing another install.

And of course, aside of checking if this is installed for the user using the installed.dat file, you can also check if it is installed locally (are the files present in "Program Files"?

This would make sure that when a user logs in on a new computer, but with an existing profile using Roaming Profile, and the install took place in his profile, nothing happens, except if the program required locally is not installed.

Comment: "placing a file in their profile directory" - the OP said in the question "there is no profile for them under \USERS\ (or equivalent folder depending on the version of Windows)."

Comment: @DavidPostill Not yet. But the user logs in, the profile folder is made, and the script for all users can then place something in their profile path and also check for the existence of this file. I've used this technique myself before so I know its solid.

Comment: OK. It might be worth clarifying that in your answer :)

Comment: @DavidPostill there you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Active Directory and a clean setup, you can assign startup scripts to Organizational Units.  If you have a general user OU, then you can follow these [instructions](https://www.petri.com/setting-up-logon-script-through-gpo-windows-server-2008) to assign a startup script to that group.

Comment: This would not prevent the script from running twice if the user logs off and in again before the user was unassigned from that OU.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you know the user's SID,
   and if `\HKEY_USERS\SID` exists, go to

   ```
   \HKEY_USERS\SID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
   ```

   and put something into `Run` or `RunOnce`.
2. Put a batch file that looks like

   ```
   if %username% == <the_user’s_name> (
           run the program
   )
   ```

   into the AllUsers startup folder.